# Minecraft style ID Grouping

Tags: python, typescript

I am currently in the works of making a Calculator for a game called ECO Global Survival, I want this calculator to not only calculate the resource requirements for X amount of Y item but also to factor in its "selling" price. ECO has it so Selling Prices are what the user wishes to set them for however on our server we follow a formula that way not all professions will get messed over.

The issue comes to items such as Logs. There is Log, Birch Log, Oak Log and so on. What I am wanting to do is "group" these in a way that minecraft does it - Dirt is ID 1 and everything else that is Dirt Related, grass podzol etc, becomes a :x

However I can not seem to find a way to do this. Would anyone here know how to do this or know of some resource that I could look at to possible find a way?

*(Coding in both Python and Typescript - Python for a Program version and Typescript for web version)*

Comment: Hi, please send more details. Did you try something? if yes, send the error. thanks

Answer (score 0):

**1. Id as an object**

Split it to 2 parts:

```
interface Indexable {
    base: number,
    tail: number,
}
```

And use like so:

```
const logIdBase = 1
const logOak = { base logIdBase, tail: 0 }
const logBirch = { base: logIdBase, tail: 1 }
```

If base is the same they are the same type of item.

**2. Bit masks**

Another way, however, is use bitmasks, like first 24 bits of int is base, the rest is tail, and if you want to get the id it is gonna be like this:

```
const idTailMask = (1 << 8) - 1
const idBaseMask = ~idTailMask
const logIdBase = 1 << 8
const logOak = logIdBase & 1
const logBirch = logIdBase & 2
```

Notice that

```
void logOak & logIdBase == logBirch & logIdBase
void logOak & idBaseMask == logIdBase
void logOak & idTailMask != logBirch & idTailMask
```

2nd way is harder to understand, but a little bit faster and consume less memory because of one number instead of two.